# Powershell matching TWO values in an array/object

Tags: regex, powershell

I'll explain what I am trying to achieve first in case there is a better way than what I have wrote. I am trying to get a list of users (but in below example I am only querying one user to test the script) who have an Exchange plan set to disabled.

The filter I need to apply is on the licenses.servicestatus object. If you run and output of this object your get:

```
ServicePlan           ProvisioningStatus
-----------           ------------------
INTUNE_O365           PendingActivation 
YAMMER_ENTERPRISE     PendingInput      
RMS_S_ENTERPRISE      Success           
OFFICESUBSCRIPTION    Success           
MCOSTANDARD           Disabled          
SHAREPOINTWAC         Disabled          
SHAREPOINTENTERPRISE  Disabled          
EXCHANGE_S_ENTERPRISE Success
```

What I need is the query to return true if it finds "disabled" in the provisioningstatus column and a matching "exchange" wildcard in the serviceplan column.

My script below does not do this, instead it returns true if it finds disabled and exchange in ANY order, IE it will always return true as long as disabled and Exchange are anywhere in the table, not where they both match on one row. This is as close as I can get as to what I want.

```
Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName "exampleuser@dom.com"| ? {"disabled" -in $_.licenses.servicestatus.provisioningstatus -and ($_.licenses.servicestatus| Out-String| ? {$_ -like "*exchange*"})}
```

I can see where I am going wrong, I just don't know how to fix it. The script is effectively running two separate searches rather than combining them together.

Also Note the reason I am using out-string is because the table above does not output serviceplan as a string.

If there is a better way of doing this then please advise otherwise I just need to know how to match two conditions in an array from the same row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this myself:

```
Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName "exampleuser@dom.com" | ? {$_.licenses.servicestatus| Out-String  | ? {$_ -like "*exchange*disabled*"}}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName "exampleuser@dom.com" | 
  ForEach-Object {
    if( ($_.licenses.serviceplan.tostring() -match 'Exchange') -and ($_.licenses.ProvisioningStatus -eq 'Disabled') )
    {
        $true
    }
    Else
    {
        $false
    }

}
```

examining your code :

```
"disabled" -in $_.licenses.servicestatus.provisioningstatus
```

wont work because

`$_.licenses` is an object with 2 properties `Servicestatus` & `Provisioningstatus`

so you can either use `$_.licenses.servicestatus` or `$_.licenses.provisioningstatus` not both together like `$_.licenses.servicestatus.provisioningstatus` because there is no such property.

Also [-in](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx) is used to check if a value is contained in an array not suitable for what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Your question got me to think about using Test-Any which i read about in an article written by @JaredPar. The basic idea is to evaluate if any item in an array of objects have a set of matching conditions.

I have put it into a module like this.

```
function Test-Any {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param([scriptblock]$EvaluateCondition,
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)] $ObjectToTest)
    begin {
        $any = $false
    }
    process {
        if (-not $any -and (& $EvaluateCondition $ObjectToTest)) {
            $any = $true
        }
    }
    end {
        $any
    }
}


function Test-All {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param([scriptblock]$EvaluateCondition,
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)] $ObjectToTest)
    begin {
        $all = $true
    }
    process {
        if ($all -and ((& $EvaluateCondition $ObjectToTest) -eq $false)) {
            $all = $false
        }
    }
    end {
        $all
    }
}

Export-ModuleMember -Function Test-Any, Test-All
```

Now as you might have noticed there is also a Test-All function. This is not used for this sample but may come in handy.

Now you can solve your task like this.

Notice i have replaced the call to Get-msoluser with some proper test data.

```
Import-Module AllAny

$testdata = @(
    (new-object psobject -Property @{ServicePlan="ExchangePlan";licenses = new-object psobject -Property @{ProvisioningStatus="Disabled"}}),
    (new-object psobject -Property @{ServicePlan="SomeOtherPlan";licenses = new-object psobject -Property @{ProvisioningStatus="Enabled"}}))

$userProp = $testdata #Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName "exampleuser@dom.com" 

if ($userProp | Test-Any {$Args.serviceplan -match "Exchange" -and $Args.licenses.ProvisioningStatus -eq 'Disabled'})
{
    echo "Do your thing!"
}
```

Hope that it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly old, but here's a slightly neater solution I came up with, given the limitations of Azure queries.

First, create a list of the users that at least include the criteria you need to match on

```
$users = Get-Msoluser -EnabledFilter EnabledOnly | 
Where { ($_.licenses.serviceplan.tostring() -match 'Exchange') `
-and ($_.licenses.ProvisioningStatus -eq 'Disabled') }
```

What you get is users that have both "Exchange" and "Disabled" somewhere within their Licenses attribute, but they may not be on the same row.

Just be cautious if you are looking for "unlicensed" users, because licenses can be reassigned. Here I'm using `Get-AzureADUser` and the AssignedPlans property instead. This user has been licensed for SfB twice, but one is still valid.

```
AssignedTimestamp   CapabilityStatus Service                       ServicePlanId
-----------------   ---------------- -------                       -------------
2019-12-05 03:46:34 Enabled          MicrosoftCommunicationsOnline 3e26ee1f-8a5f-4d52-aee2-b81ce45c8f40
2019-09-26 07:16:48 Deleted          MicrosoftCommunicationsOnline 4828c8ec-dc2e-4779-b502-87ac9ce28ab7
```

After doing the first pass to populate the `$users` list, to get users where you have at least row that has an Exchange & Disabled value, check each user's Licenses attribute with a `Where` statement on both properties. The following dumps the UPN into `$licensedUsers` for later export.

```
$licensedUsers = @()
$users | Foreach {
    $u = $_
    if ($u.licenses | where { ($_.serviceplan.tostring() -match 'Exchange') `
        -and ($_.ProvisioningStatus -eq 'Disabled') }) {
        $licensedUsers += $u.userPrincipalName
        #if you want more properties in the report, create a PSCustomObject here instead
    }
}
```

If you only wanted to get the users that don't have any valid Exchange licenses at all, you'd want to reverse the logic to find accounts where all the licences are **not enabled**.

```
if (-not ($u.licenses | where { ($_.serviceplan.tostring() -match 'Exchange') `
-and ($_.ProvisioningStatus -eq 'Enabled')) })
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things to do this in one line (as far as I can tell):

- Use nested Where-Objects to check each object down the tree
- No need to convert ServicePlan to a string if you use the 'servicename' property underneath it

So I think this should meet the original posters' requirements in a single command:

```
Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName "exampleuser@dom.com" | Where-Object { $_.Licenses.ServiceStatus | Where-Object { $_.ServicePlan.ServiceName -like "*exchange*" -and $_.ProvisioningStatus -eq "Disabled" } }
```

Or for a shorter command:

```
Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName "exampleuser@dom.com" | ? { $_.Licenses.ServiceStatus | ? { $_.ServicePlan.ServiceName -like "*exchange*" -and $_.ProvisioningStatus -eq "Disabled" } }
```